# Retry PowerShell script (.ps1) if failing with specific error message

Tags: powershell, cakebuild

We have a PowerShell build script (Cake bootstrapper) that occasionally fails to download/restore nuget packages. How would I create a generic .ps1 script that can be used to make calls to another .ps1 script, and retry if failed and the output contained a specific string (I don't want to retry if it's a build error)?

Possible example usage:

```
.\ExecuteWithRetry.ps1 -Script "Build.ps1 -target Restore" -OutputTrigger "RemoteException"
```

Comment: Do a search for "error handling in PowerShell" for more information on how to get started.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that, thanks Bill!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a script that does the trick.

Example usage:

```
./Execute-With-Retry.ps1 -RetryDelay 1 -MaxRetries 2 { & ./Build.ps1 -target Restore } -RetryFilter RemoteException
```

Based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alexbevi/34b700ff7c7c53c7780b) from [Alex Bevilacqua](http://www.alexbevi.com/).

```
<#
This script can be used to pass a ScriptBlock (closure) to be executed and returned.

The operation retried a few times on failure, and if the maximum threshold is surpassed, the operation fails completely.

Params:
    Command         - The ScriptBlock to be executed
    RetryDelay      - Number (in seconds) to wait between retries
                      (default: 5)
    MaxRetries      - Number of times to retry before accepting failure
                      (default: 5)
    VerboseOutput   - More info about internal processing
                      (default: false)

    RetyFilter      - Only retry if retry filter value is contained in the command output

Examples:

./Execute-With-Retry.ps1 -RetryDelay 1 -MaxRetries 2 { & ./Build.ps1 -target Restore } -RetryFilter RemoteException

#>
param(    
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
  $Command,    
  $RetryDelay = 5,
  $MaxRetries = 5,
  $VerboseOutput = $false,
  $RetryFilter
)

$currentRetry = 0
$success = $false
$cmd = $Command.ToString()

do {
  try {
    $result = & $Command
    $success = $true
    if ($VerboseOutput -eq $true) {
      $Host.UI.WriteDebugLine("Successfully executed [$cmd]")
    }

    return $result
  }
  catch [System.Exception] {
    $currentRetry = $currentRetry + 1

    $exMessage = $_.Exception.Message;
    if ($RetryFilter -AND !$exMessage.Contains($RetryFilter)) {
      throw $exMessage
    }

    if ($VerboseOutput -eq $true) {
      $Host.UI.WriteErrorLine("Failed to execute [$cmd]: " + $_.Exception.Message)
    }

    if ($currentRetry -gt $MaxRetries) {                
      throw "Could not execute [$cmd]. The error: " + $_.Exception.ToString()
    }
    else {
      if ($VerboseOutput -eq $true) {
        $Host.UI.WriteDebugLine("Waiting $RetryDelay second(s) before attempt #$currentRetry of [$cmd]")
      }
      Start-Sleep -s $RetryDelay
    }
  }
} while (!$success);
```